# How to effeciently SELECT Nested dependency Tables using JOIN in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm having One Parent Table "Employee", the Employee Information is stored in 3 Children Tables and each children table has one children Table. Consider the following Tables

Table : Employee (Level #1)

```
EmpId    IsActive
__________________
1        1
2        1
3        1
4        0
5        0
6        1
```

Table : EmployeeEmail (Level #2)

```
EmpEmailId    EmpId    EmailId
______________________________
1             1         1
2             4         3
3             6         4
```

Table : EmailAddress (Level #3)

```
EmailId    Email
____________________________
1          one@gmail.com
2          two@gmail.com
3          three@gmail.com
4          four@gmail.com
```

Table : EmployeePhone (Level #2)

```
EmpPhoneId    EmpId    PhoneId
______________________________
1             1         1
2             2         2
3             5         4
```

Table : PhoneNumber (Level #3)

```
PhoneId    PhoneNumber
_______________________
1          9912345671
2          9912345672
3          9912345673
4          9912345674
```

Now I need to Select the **Active Employee Records** (Full Information), if the employee has phone number then it should come otherwise it should be NULL, I need the same for Email too.

Kindly assist me how to Join this structure and fetch the records efficiently ?

Comment: You'll need a LEFT OUTER JOIN and then you'll have to think what happens in the possible many-to-many join case between the records.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query once it may help you.

```
 select EMP.EmpId, EMP_ADD.Email,PH_NBR.PhoneNumber 
 from Employee EMP
 LEFT JOIN EmployeeEmail EMP_EM ON EMP.EMP_ID=EmpId
 LEFT JOIN EmailAddress EMP_ADD ON EMP_ADD.EmailId=EMP_EM.EmpEmailId
 LEFT JOIN EmployeePhone EMP_PH ON EMP_PH.EmpId=EMP.EmpId
 LEFT JOIN PhoneNumber PH_NBR ON PH_NBR.PhoneId=EMP_PH.PhoneId
 WHERE EMP.IsActive=1
```

Note: Here i assume Active as 1 and Inactive as  0.in case if it is reverse then change **where EMP.IsActive=0**

(OR) Try this.here i'm trying to the phone and email data separately then joining them with emp_id

```
;with email as 
(
 select EMP.EmpId, EMP_ADD.Email
 from Employee EMP
 LEFT JOIN EmployeeEmail EMP_EM ON EMP.EMP_ID=EmpId
 LEFT JOIN EmailAddress EMP_ADD ON EMP_ADD.EmailId=EMP_EM.EmpEmailId
 WHERE EMP.IsActive=1
 )
 ,Phone as
 (
 select EMP.EmpId,PH_NBR.PhoneNumber 
 from Employee EMP
 LEFT JOIN EmployeePhone EMP_PH ON EMP_PH.EmpId=EMP.EmpId
 LEFT JOIN PhoneNumber PH_NBR ON PH_NBR.PhoneId=EMP_PH.PhoneId
 WHERE EMP.IsActive=1
)
select * from email e
left join Phone p on p.EmpId=e.EmpId
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative form:

- only the three tables that you actually need are in the main query
- the junction tables are used to glue them together via `ON EXISTS(...)`:

---

```
SELECT e.empid, em.email, pn.phonenumber
 FROM employee e
 LEFT JOIN emailaddress em 
        ON EXISTS ( -- junctiontable
        SELECT * FROM employeeemail ee
        WHERE ee.empid = e.emp_id
        AND ee.empemailid = em.emailid
        )
 LEFT JOIN phonenumber pn 
        ON EXISTS( -- junctiontable
        SELECT * FROM employeephone ep
        WHERE ep.empid = e.empid
        AND ep.phoneid = pn.phoneid
        )
 WHERE e.isactive=1
        ;
```