# Efficiently select nested dependency tables and multiple columns in a single row using join in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, left-join, outer-join

I have one parent table "Employee", the employee information is stored in three children tables and each children table has one children table. Consider the following tables:

Table: Employee (Level #1)

```
EmpId    IsActive
__________________
1        1
2        1
3        1
4        0
5        0
6        1
```

Table: EmployeeEmail (Level #2)

```
EmpEmailId    EmpId    EmailId
______________________________
1             1         1
2             4         3
3             6         4
```

Table: EmailAddress (Level #3)

```
EmailId    Email
____________________________
1          one@gmail.com
2          two@gmail.com
3          three@gmail.com
4          four@gmail.com
```

Table: EmployeePhone (Level #2)

```
EmpPhoneId    EmpId    PhoneId    Type
____________________________________________
1             1         1         Mobile
2             2         2         Mobile
3             5         4         Fax
4             1         6         Fax
5             2         9         Home
```

Table: PhoneNumber (Level #3)

```
PhoneId    PhoneNumber
_______________________
1          9912345671
2          9912345672
3          9912345673
4          9912345674
5          9912345675
6          9912345676
7          9912345677
8          9912345678
9          9912345679
```

Now I need to select the **Active Employee Records** (Full Information), if the employee has phone number then it should come otherwise it should be NULL, I need the same for Email too.

My expected output:

```
EmpId        Email             Home        Mobile        Fax
____________________________________________________________________
  1          one@gmail.com     NULL        9912345671    9912345676
(...)
```

This question is similar to my previous question [How to effeciently SELECT Nested dependency Tables using JOIN in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156284/how-to-effeciently-select-nested-dependency-tables-using-join-in-sql-server)

Kindly assist me how to **fetch the multiple phone numbers in a single row**?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `case` style `pivot` that looks like it would suit your needs:

```
select 
      e.EmpId
    , Email  = max(em.Email)
    , Home   = max(case when ep.Type = 'Home'   then pn.PhoneNumber else null end)
    , Mobile = max(case when ep.Type = 'Mobile' then pn.PhoneNumber else null end)
    , Fax    = max(case when ep.Type = 'Fax'    then pn.PhoneNumber else null end)
  from Employee as e
    left join EmployeeEmail as ee on  e.EmpId   = ee.EmpId
    left join EmailAddress  as ea on ee.EmailId = ea.EmailId
    left join EmployeePhone as ep on  e.EmpId   = ep.EmpId
    left join PhoneNumber   as pn on ep.PhoneId = pn.PhoneId
  where e.IsActive = 1
  group by e.EmpId
```